# Find date file was last modified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filemtime

I am setting up a page that will display the last date the file was modified. From what I understand I need to mtime to get this date, but how to do I reference the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass it a string of the file name.

```
irb(main):001:0> File.mtime("Gemfile")
=> 2016-08-22 13:54:43 -0700
```

To reference files from within rails you can use `Rails.root.join`:

```
gemfile = Rails.root.join("Gemfile")
=> #<Pathname:/Users/username/projects/appname/Gemfile>

File.mtime(gemfile)
=> 2016-08-22 13:54:43 -0700
```

The [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-mtime) also mention you can pass it an [IO object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
File.mtime("/home/user/path/file.rb")
```